# Getting a DataGridView to show hex

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using DataGridView to display my object. I did this by setting the DataSource equal to object which works for displaying its data in columns but some of the data needs to be represented in hex which I can't figure out. For example, I have the following object and I want MainModuleBase to be denoted in hex rather than decimal form.

```
    public class Summary
    {
        public int ProcessId { get; private set; }
        public string ProcessName { get; private set; }
        public ulong MainModuleBase { get; private set; }
```

The auto formatting is sort of weird for this, but it basically looks like this.

```
this.dumpGrid.DataSource = this.processSummaryBindingSource2;
// More stuff here
this.processSummaryBindingSource2.DataSource = typeof(Summary);

this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.DataPropertyName = "MainModuleBase";
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.FillWeight = 80F;
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.HeaderText = "MainModuleBase";
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.MinimumWidth = 80;
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3";
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.ReadOnly = true;
```

Then in a after some buttons have been clicked I do `processSummaryBindingSource2.DataSource = result;` which works but it's not denoted in hex any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-7.0 you want to put a "X" into DefaultCellStyle.Format of your column

Comment: @Ralf Oh amazing thank you for that! Is there a way to prefix it with 0x? I know its not really needed but it would be nice for display purposes.

Comment: There's a sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icustomformatter?view=net-7.0) which you may be able to use - _"The following example implements ICustomFormatter to allow .. hexadecimal formatting of integral values"_

Comment: @stuartd Oh that looks helpful, but after I set my data by doing ``processSummaryBindingSource2.DataSource = summery`` would I have to go back through the columns and change their values? If so, how exactly can I do that because I tried that before without any luck.

Comment: Nope, you set `dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.Columns["MainModuleBase"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = [Your Custom Formatter]`. Or you can handle the `CellFormatting` event and format the value when requested. Something like `e.Value = $"0x{((ulong)e.Value).ToString("X2")}";` (of course when `e.RowIndex >= 0` and `e.ColumnIndex == 2`)

Comment: @Jimi How do I register the cell formatting event? ``this.dumpGrid.CellFormatting += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);``

Comment: Just use the Form's Designer, select your DataGridView, change the Properties pane to the event viewer, double click the `CellFormatting` event and an event handler is created for you. Add your code there